# Yii2 Gii : You are not allowed to access this page

Tags: yii2, gii

I'm using Yii2 advance template and I can access gii tool successfully in my local machine.
But when I upload it into real server, there is a message "You are not allowed to access this page."
Could you tell me which file should I have to config  and could you print screen or paste the whole content of that config file?

Thanks you before hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply add your IP address in gii config :

```
'gii' => [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'] // adjust this to your needs
],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

**EDIT** : in advanced app, gii conf is in

- `environments/dev/backend/config/main-local.php`
- `environments/dev/frontend/config/main-local.php`

Comment: Sorry which filename should I use?